# Veracode sql injection solution

Tags: java, prepared-statement, sql-injection, epoch, veracode

I am using the following query in a Java class to connect and get details from a table from Oracle.

```sql
select * from mytable 
where DOCTYPE = 'CDA' 
and To_char(DATE '1970-01-01' +  (STATEMENTENDDATE-1),'YYYY-MM-DD') between ? and ?";
```

This is giving SQL injection flaw in veracode scan.

I need to have `To_char(DATE '1970-01-01' +  (STATEMENTENDDATE-1),'YYYY-MM-DD')` as second parameter as I am reading epoch time in human readable form.

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to pass the 2 parameters separately as Strings, but got the same issue.

Comment: SQL injection happens in the source code, not just the SQL script. You have to share a minimum reproducible example including your Java code for others to understand the issue.